# What is a reasonable mechanism for the following reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbohydrates, heterocyclic-compounds, nitriles

[image: Write a reasonable mechanisms for the following reaction]

Hello all! I'm stuck on this one question and am not sure how to finish the mechanism. What I did was attack the alkyne first with the N farthest to the left. I'm not sure what do to after that though. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Michael attack by the ring N, as you describe then cyclisation onto the protonated CN by the exocyclic NH2

Comment: I’m trying to figure out how or what to attack after the ring-nitrogen attack of the alkyne. When I attack the resulting product from the first step with the exocyclic N I get a very strained cyclic structure with two consecutive alkenes within the 6 membered heterocycle. Does that sound like the right way to do this mechanism?

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  The neutral intermediate has an acrylonitrile unit added to the ring N, and =NH exo to the ring.

Comment: I think I got it... 
1) attack alkyne with cyclic N and protonate nitrile
2) push LP on nitrile-N back into conj. system and protonate one of the alkenes, getting the the acrylonitrile intermediate you mentioned
3) attack nitrile-C, forming a six membered ring
4) delocalize middle N LP to the left most N

Comment: Don't forget the contribution of the ring O to step 3