# Mechanism of heterocyclic ring formation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, heterocyclic-compounds

I saw a question here about the mechanism for a heterocyclic ring formation: [What is a reasonable mechanism for the following reaction?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97956/what-is-a-reasonable-mechanism-for-the-following-reaction/98505?noredirect=1#comment182202_98505). I tried solving the mechanism but I am missing something. Let me explain my reasoning:

This is the reaction:
[image]

I started protonating the nitrile N, followed by the attack of the cyclic N to the terminal alkyne carbon. Then I couldn't figure out what happens next, so I assumed the triple bond attacks a proton and forms the acrylonitrile intermediate (I am 99.99% sure this is not what happens). Then the exo N attacks the nitrile carbon and form the 6-membered ring, followed by a proton exchange between the imino nitrogen and the protonated cyclic amino group (again, I feel this is ridiculously wrong). The lone pair on the cyclic amino group form the double C=N bond, however, I still end with a protonated N that is not in the product.

[image]

Can someone explain to me what I am missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79172/discussion-on-question-by-raul-luciano-mechanism-of-heterocyclic-ring-formation).